# What is a Vienna Schnitzel?

Tags: meat, language

I have heard this term frequently used, but I haven't been able to find a definition, even in the [extensive Wikipedia Article on Schnitzel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnitzel).

Comment: I can tell from my own experience that these can be **huge** and very tasty :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked to references this dish as "Wiener Schnitzel". That article defines it as veal--pounded, breaded, and fried--garnished with lemon, and served with potatoes.

"Wiener" refers to its Viennese origin, and Schnitzel to the type of preparation (pounded, breaded, and fried). There are many varieties of Schnitzels, made of several different meats, and with various sauces. Jaeger Schnitzel, for examples, is served with a creamy mushroom sauce. The one from Vienna is served with lemon and potatoes.

Comment: and is usually pork, not veal.

Comment: @jwenting, real Wiener Schnitzel is veal. I can imagine somebody making it from pork, but nobody in a German speaking country will accept that as a true Wiener Schnitzel. On the other hand, the use of French fries instead of potatoes is common, and nobody takes an offense.

Comment: I think jwentig meant that Jaeger Schnitzel is more often pork than veal, which I'd agree with.

Comment: I have never had the experience of having Wiener Schnitzel in Germany that is from veal; mostly it is from pork. In Germany, Wiener Schnitzel is usually bigger in size. In a traditional restaurant, fried potatoes and onions (at certain ones, red onions) are served as _Beilage_ (side dish), while at most generic dinners French fries are usually served. I have cut down on meat years ago; but I am becoming a little hungry while typing this out..